# How to go "up" with path in tsconfig?

Tags: tsconfig

So I have monorepo with two projects, something like this:

```
main_repo/
|
--- e2e_tests/
|
--- app/
```

declared paths in `tsconfig.json` in `e2e_tests/` - for example

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@actions": ["cypress/support/utils/app/actions"],
      "@app-locators": ["../app/something/here.ts"]
    },
    "types": ["node", "cypress", "cypress-each"]
  },
  "include": ["cypress/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and it works when I import something with `@actions` in `e2e_tests/`, but when after `@actions` path I add `"@app-locators": ["../app/something/here.ts"]` I get issue when importing in `e2e_tests/` that I have to install... my app as package? Question - how to make it works with path to the "above" directory?

> '@main_repo/app' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S @main_repo/app' to add it eslintimport/no-extraneous-dependencies

Comment: To leave to the "above" directory use `../`.

Comment: @Itik I did - in `"@app-locators": ["../app/something/here.ts"]`

Comment: If you import the file to a directory and in the file you import there is a path to a file that is in the directory you imported from, you don't need to leave to the parent directory.

Comment: ah so you mean to change it to the "relative" path like this: `"@app-locators": ["./../widget/src/global/types/widget-locators.ts"]` ? It's asking for the same thing - to install it to the project's dependencies.

Comment: No exactly what I meant. But can you show a picture of your directory?

Comment: I well... can't, private project - I can try to create separate project for reproduction only and share it

Comment: No need to share your code. Just the directory's name. But a separate project example would work too :)